# How fast is Python Image Library's (PIL) ImageDraw Module, for instance as compared to OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, python-imaging-library, gpu

I have some .png images and I want to be able to quickly:

(a) Load a .png from a file.
(b) Draw some simple lines on top of the .png.
(c) Get the contents (bytes) of the resulting image to return as the result of an http request.

It sounds like PIL is a good candidate for doing this with relatively little code. However, I'm trying to understand how efficient it is, especially when I have, say, thousands of lines to draw in step (b). The alternative is using PyOpenGL, but before getting into that I wanted to understand if PIL was already fast enough.

I was going to ask if PIL used OpenGL under the covers. But that might be the wrong question, because my understanding is that to get the real speed benefit from PyOpenGL I'd want to submit my line vertexes as NumPy arrays. So presumably even if PIL uses OpenGL, I'm going to lose a lot of that benefit when I make an individual PIL call to draw each of my lines?

Anybody have concrete data for speed of PIL when drawing lots of primitives?

Comment: To use OpenGL, you need a OpenGL context. This could be difficult if you are planning to use this software from a headless server (as implied by the http request response requirement).

Comment: @tkerwin: The difficulty of getting a headless context varies considerably based on OS.  Hopefully @M Katz will let us know more about the environment.  Of course, one can always create a hidden window, but it might not be accelerated in some environments.

Comment: Certainly true, and I don't know for sure, but I would guess using OpenGL would be faster than PIL if accelerated and slower if not.

Comment: I have more control over my servers than some, although I'm not sure they will always have a GPU (by "headless" you mean "lacking a GPU and perhaps lacking a graphics card at all," right?). However, I was hoping that by using OpenGL I'd get hardware acceleration if it was there, and good software rendering if it wasn't. Not so? My understanding was that OpenGL was lower-level than the "window" concept, so I can do whatever drawing I wanted regardless of whether it could actually be displayed on that system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Draw some simple lines on top of the .png"* is not a computationally intensive task.

This doesn't seems to be a good candidate for the GPU since they are better suited for more complex tasks. You've got to realize that the image is initially loaded on the RAM, making it your job to send this data to the GPU memory and then retrieve it back. This operation consumes a few milliseconds, depending on the size of the image, that could be better used for CPU processing.

Your application would only benefit from the GPU if it had high arithmetic intensity.

Comment: I thought an advantage of OpenGL and/or hardware acceleration in general was not just computing rotations and such, but simply handling huge numbers of drawing actions quickly (if submitted in a single call). So like, drawing ten thousand points or little lines would be faster (than drawing it in a higher-level way) even though there is not much to "compute". No?

Comment: It's not clear whether something of that magnitude would be faster on the GPU. I encourage you to write a CPU application to do that first.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try some experiments with PIL and report back on what I find...

Comment: So what did you find after your experiment @MKatz ?

Comment: @Iamhoangtung, I learned that I hate Python. For the types of applications I write, I am processing lots of data, and every part of the application has to be fast. I found that with Python, no matter how much I tried to use libraries like PIL and numPy, every single loop in the program that was left in Python was too slow. So now it's fully in C++ and for the drawing I use the CImg library (without GPU) and it's fast enough.

Comment: @MKatz Thanks for coming back to this post after a decade and share that info. I'm sure it will help others in the future.